# Read master details data from XML file in SQL Server

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath, xml-namespaces, sql-server-2016

I have a XML file like that :

```
<invoice xmlns:xsi="http://......" xmlns="http://..." xmlns:omismsg="http://..." omismsg:action="update">

    <status>1</status>
    <transNo>17AUAU0000118N</transNo>
    <transType>5</transType>
    <externalRefId/>
    <billExternalRef/>

    <invoiceDetails omismsg:action="update">
        <transNo>17AUAU0000118N</transNo>
        <transType>5</transType>
        <seqNo>001</seqNo>
    </invoiceDetails>

    <invoiceDetails omismsg:action="update">
        <transNo>17AUAU0000118N</transNo>
        <transType>5</transType>
        <seqNo>002</seqNo>
    </invoiceDetails>

</invoice>
```

I have wrote this command to extract all data

```
select
 c3.value('status[1]','int'),
 c3.value('transNo[1]','VARCHAR(255)'),
 c3.value('transType[1]','int'),
 c3.value('externalRefId[1]','VARCHAR(255)'),
 c3.value('billExternalRef[1]','VARCHAR(255)')

 ,c4.value('(transNo)[1]','VARCHAR(10)')
 ,c4.value('(transType)[1]','int')
 ,c4.value('(seqNo)[1]','VARCHAR(10)')
from
(
  select 
    cast(c1 as xml)
  from 
    OPENROWSET (BULK '\\SQL-CSLDataWarehousedevelopment\ETL-ToIMOS\test\invoice.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) as T1(c1)
)as T2(c2)
cross apply c2.nodes('/invoice') T3(c3)
cross apply c2.nodes('/invoice/invoiceDetails') T4(c4)
```

But the result is empty.

I checked the XML file and I found that if I replace

```
<invoice xmlns:xsi="http://......" xmlns="http://..." xmlns:omismsg="http://..." omismsg:action="update">
```

with

```
<invoice>
```

and

```
<invoiceDetails omismsg:action="update">
```

with

```
<invoiceDetails>
```

It will work. 
But in reality i can change the xml file. How should I change my command to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a namespace issue. There are two approaches to come by

- wildcard the namespace
- (Recommended) Declare and use the namespace

Try this

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<invoice xmlns:xsi="http://......" xmlns="http://..." xmlns:omismsg="http://..." omismsg:action="update">
  <status>1</status>
  <transNo>17AUAU0000118N</transNo>
  <transType>5</transType>
  <externalRefId />
  <billExternalRef />
  <invoiceDetails omismsg:action="update">
    <transNo>17AUAU0000118N</transNo>
    <transType>5</transType>
    <seqNo>001</seqNo>
  </invoiceDetails>
  <invoiceDetails omismsg:action="update">
    <transNo>17AUAU0000118N</transNo>
    <transType>5</transType>
    <seqNo>002</seqNo>
  </invoiceDetails>
</invoice>';
```

--This query will use the `*:` to ignore the namespace

```
select
 c3.value('(*:status/text())[1]','int'),
 c3.value('(*:transNo/text())[1]','VARCHAR(255)'),
 c3.value('(*:transType/text())[1]','int'),
 c3.value('(*:externalRefId/text())[1]','VARCHAR(255)'),
 c3.value('(*:billExternalRef/text())[1]','VARCHAR(255)'),
 c3.value('(@*:action)[1]','varchar(255)')

 ,c4.value('(*:transNo/text())[1]','VARCHAR(10)')
 ,c4.value('(*:transType/text())[1]','int')
 ,c4.value('(*:seqNo/text())[1]','VARCHAR(10)')
 ,c4.value('(@*:action)[1]','VARCHAR(10)')
from @xml.nodes('/*:invoice') T3(c3)
cross apply c3.nodes('*:invoiceDetails') T4(c4);
```

--this query declares the namespaces and use them accordingly

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://...'
                          ,'http://...' AS omismsg)
select
 c3.value('(status/text())[1]','int'),
 c3.value('(transNo/text())[1]','VARCHAR(255)'),
 c3.value('(transType/text())[1]','int'),
 c3.value('(externalRefId/text())[1]','VARCHAR(255)'),
 c3.value('(billExternalRef/text())[1]','VARCHAR(255)'),
 c3.value('(@omismsg:action)[1]','varchar(255)')

 ,c4.value('(transNo/text())[1]','VARCHAR(10)')
 ,c4.value('(transType/text())[1]','int')
 ,c4.value('(seqNo/text())[1]','VARCHAR(10)')
 ,c4.value('(@omismsg:action)[1]','VARCHAR(10)')
from @xml.nodes('/invoice') T3(c3)
cross apply c3.nodes('invoiceDetails') T4(c4);
```

Both return the same